# How to prevent a double submit of a form, reusing a modal with a different button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal with checkboxes and I am trying to reuse it for 2 buttons that pull the info to 2 different spots on the site.

The problem is from JQuery.  Things will submit but if I press `Button A` then everything works fine.  If I press `Button B` after this then `Button A` will resubmit and `Button B` will submit too.  This also happens if you do the buttons in the opposite order.

We have the main page that is a form. This modal pops up a form with button A. You select a policy and then click submit. This adds it to the main form. If you select a policy with button B it adds policy files. Similar but slightly different but still they both use the same modal

A modal pops up from pressing this.

```
<a href="#" data-mylink="1" role='button' class="btn btn-default" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#policyattach_instructions1'>Button A</a>

<a href="#" data-mylink="2" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#policyattach_instructions1">Button B</a>
```

Submit button on Modal.  It checks if the checkbox is checked with the click of the button and doesn't get in the way of the JQuery.

```
 <input type="button" name="action" class="btn btn-success ajaxifypolicies2" value="Add Policy" onClick="if(radio_checkbox_validate(document.add_policies_form,'one or more Policies & Procedures.')) { return true; } else { return false; }" />
```

JQuery:

```
$('#policyattach_instructions1').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#add_policies_display').html("<center style='margin-top: 25px;'>Use the search tools above to find Policies & Procedures.</center>");
  var btn = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var pnpid = btn.data('mylink');
  //alert(pnpid);
  if(pnpid==1){
    $(".ajaxifypolicies2").click(function(){
            alert("test98");
            $('[id^="add_policies_checkbox"]').each(function(i, v){
                if($(v).prop('checked')){
                var data=$(v).val();
                //alert(data);
                $("#linked_pnp_instructions").append("<div id='pnpID_instruction"+data+"1'><h6><input type=hidden name=pnpID_instructions value=\'"+data+"\' />P&P #'s: "+data+" <a href='#' class='clear_pnp' id='pnpID_instruction"+data+"'>Clear</a></h6></div>");
                //$("#policyattach_instructions1").removeData('bs.modal');


                }
            });/**/
            $(".clear_pnp").click(function(){
                var ID=this.id;
                //alert(ID+"1");
                $("#"+ID+"1").remove();
                return false;
            });
            $("#policyattach_instructions1").modal('hide');
    });//end ajaxifypolicies/**/
  }
  else 
  {
    $(".ajaxifypolicies2").click(function(){
            alert("test99");

            $('[id^="add_policies_checkbox"]').each(function(i, v){
                if($(v).prop('checked')){
                var data=$(v).val();
                //alert(data);
                $("#linked_pnp").append("<div id='pnpIDs"+data+"1'><h6><input type=hidden name=pnpIDs value=\'"+data+"\' />P&P #'s: "+data+" <a href=# class=clear_pnp id='pnpIDs"+data+"' >Clear</a></h6></div>");
                //$("#policyattach_instructions1").removeData('bs.modal');
                //  $("#policyattach_instructions1").modal('hide');

                }
            });/**/
            $(".clear_pnp").click(function(){
                var ID=this.id;
                //alert(ID+"1");
                $("#"+ID+"1").remove();
                return false;
            });
            $("#policyattach_instructions1").modal('hide');
    });//end ajaxifypolicies/**/
  }
    return false;/**/
});//end modal
    $('#policyattach_instructions1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        alert("asfdasf");
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
```

I also tried this to try and avoid using ajaxifypolicies2 twice:

```
$(".ajaxifypolicies2").click(function(){
        if(pnpid==1){
            alert("test98");
            $('[id^="add_policies_checkbox"]').each(function(i, v){
                if($(v).prop('checked')){
                var data=$(v).val();
                //alert(data);
                $("#linked_pnp_instructions").append("<div id='pnpID_instruction"+data+"1'><h6><input type=hidden name=pnpID_instructions value=\'"+data+"\' />P&P #'s: "+data+" <a href='#' class='clear_pnp' id='pnpID_instruction"+data+"'>Clear</a></h6></div>");
                //$("#policyattach_instructions1").removeData('bs.modal');


                }
            });/**/
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("test99");

            $('[id^="add_policies_checkbox"]').each(function(i, v){
                if($(v).prop('checked')){
                var data=$(v).val();
                //alert(data);
                $("#linked_pnp").append("<div id='pnpIDs"+data+"1'><h6><input type=hidden name=pnpIDs value=\'"+data+"\' />P&P #'s: "+data+" <a href=# class=clear_pnp id='pnpIDs"+data+"' >Clear</a></h6></div>");
                //$("#policyattach_instructions1").removeData('bs.modal');
                //  $("#policyattach_instructions1").modal('hide');

                }
            });/**/
        }
            $(".clear_pnp").click(function(){
                var ID=this.id;
                //alert(ID+"1");
                $("#"+ID+"1").remove();
                return false;
            });
            $("#policyattach_instructions1").modal('hide');
    });//end ajaxifypolicies/**/



    return false;/**/
});//end modal
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here? Can't seem to understand your post

Comment: We have the main page that is a form.  This modal pops up a form with button A.  You select a policy and then click submit.  This adds it to the main form.  If you select a policy with button B it adds policy files.  Similar but slightly different but still they both use the same modal.  I will update this to the question.

Comment: any chance of simplifying and putting it into a plunker or fiddle?  It really helps make fixing the issues easier.

Comment: Sure, it make take some time, but I'll try

Comment: Are you trying to make a wizard form? you can use any plugins to have a better UI not just only a modal.

Comment: Basically it is like a wizard...  Jquery stores the values then each time the modal gets opened again it doesn't start over, it keeps the old form data.  So I  think it must be some kind of caching value that needs to be cleared  (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#policyattach_instructions1').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $('#add_policies_display').html("<center style='margin-top: 25px;'>Use the search tools above to find Policies & Procedures.</center>");

 // alert("testy");
  var btn = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var pnpid = btn.data('mylink');
  //var pnpid = $(this).data('mylink');
  //alert(pnpid);

    $(".ajaxifypolicies2").click(function(){

        alert(pnpid);
        if(pnpid==1){
            alert("test98");
            pnpid = ("");
            $('[id^="add_policies_checkbox"]').each(function(i, v){
                if($(v).prop('checked')){
                var data=$(v).val();
                //alert(data);
                $("#linked_pnp_instructions").append("<div id='pnpID_instruction"+data+"1'><h6><input type=hidden name=pnpID_instructions value=\'"+data+"\' />P&P #'s: "+data+" <a href='#' class='clear_pnp' id='pnpID_instruction"+data+"'>Clear</a></h6></div>");
                //$("#policyattach_instructions1").removeData('bs.modal');

                }
            });/**/
        }
```

removed the Else If and made it an if only

```
        if(pnpid==2)
        {
            alert("test99");
```

Prevented multiple values from being submitted from previous submits  pnpid=("");

```
            pnpid = ("");
            $('[id^="add_policies_checkbox"]').each(function(i, v){
                if($(v).prop('checked')){
                var data=$(v).val();
                //alert(data);
                $("#linked_pnp").append("<div id='pnpIDs"+data+"1'><h6><input type=hidden name=pnpIDs value=\'"+data+"\' />P&P #'s: "+data+" <a href=# class=clear_pnp id='pnpIDs"+data+"' >Clear</a></h6></div>");
                //$("#policyattach_instructions1").removeData('bs.modal');
                //  $("#policyattach_instructions1").modal('hide');
                }
            });/**/
        }
            $(".clear_pnp").click(function(){
                var ID=this.id;
                //alert(ID+"1");
                $("#"+ID+"1").remove();
                return false;
            });
            $("#policyattach_instructions1").modal('hide');
    });//end ajaxifypolicies/**/



    return false;/**/
});//end modal
```